# Any suggestion how can I optimize this query

Tags: mysql

There is a table in my system `tbl1` having more than 10 million records. The query below takes 40 seconds to execute. I have already created an index on foreign key and columns in `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` clause. Secondly, tried `INNER JOIN` instead of subquery.

```
SELECT * FROM tb1 
INNER JOIN tbl2 
ON tbl1.column1_id=tbl2.columnpk_id
WHERE tb1.columnpk_id IN (
    select max(columnpk_id)
    FROM tbl1 where created_at < ('2022-02-16 09:30:01'-INTERVAL 24 hour) 
    group by tbl1.column1_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `IN` clause might causing the slowness issue.
Why not try `RIGH JOIN` clause to improve the query like below:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tb1 
RIGHT JOIN (select max(columnpk_id) as columnpk_id
FROM tbl1 where created_at < ('2022-02-16 09:30:01'-INTERVAL 24 hour) group by column1_id) AS filtered_tbl1
ON tbl1.columnpk_id = filtered_tbl1.columnpk_id
INNER JOIN tbl2 
ON tbl1.column1_id=tbl2.columnpk_id
```

Comment: It does not affect much.Can you please suggest anything else.Sub query takes ony 3 seconds,with join it will take approx 40 second.